# How to integrate $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ without using trigonometric identities or partial fractions? Thanks!

Comment: Why this question ?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a 'shortcut', as I struggled in a question involving this.

Comment: Will be hard to find a shortcut in something which is already very short.

Comment: It's a basic formula: $\operatorname{argtanh}x$ or $\dfrac12\ln\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac{1-x+x}{1-x^2}=\frac1{1+x}+\frac x{1-x^2}$$ hence

$$\log(1+x)-\frac12\log(1-x^2).$$

(Not much different from a decomposition in simple fractions.)

Comment: why does u substitution not work here?

Comment: @moon What ????

Comment: when i have 1/(1-x^2), why does using the u substitution method not work here?(Back substituting)

Comment: @Moon Which substitution ? Who said that it doesn't work ? By the way, you forbid trigonometric identities, while the answer is an hyperbolic function.

Comment: Sorry about the trouble, but if it did work how would it work?

Comment: @Moon: $u=\tanh x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing (Sorry for all the trouble) but why could u not equal 1-x^2 and du=-2x dx?

Comment: @Moon: who the Hell said that it couldn't ??? Try it !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44268/discussion-between-moon-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @Moon: no, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lookup a table of derivatives and spot

$$(\text{artanh } x)'=\frac1{1-x^2}.$$

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$\frac { 1 }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 1-x } +\frac { 1 }{ 1+x }  \right] $$

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want to know how to do it without partial fractions please.

Answer (score 1):

Use, the series representation:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n(1+(-1)^n)}{2}$$

So, we get:

$$\text{I}=\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n(1+(-1)^n)}{2}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\int x^n\space\text{d}x$$

Now, use:

- $$\int x^n\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1+n}}{1+n}+\text{C}$$

So:

$$\text{I}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\cdot\frac{x^{1+n}}{1+n}+\text{C}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1+n}(1+(-1)^n)}{2(1+n)}+\text{C}$$

---

Using, partial fractions like @haqnatural, gives us:

$$\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\ln|1+x|-\ln|1-x|}{2}+\text{C}$$

Because:

- $$\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\ln|x|+\text{C}$$